# Difference in Results Between Two Hive Queries with and without a Time Partition Condition

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have two Hive queries that I'm running against a table, and I'm getting different results, but I'm not entirely sure why. I'd like to understand the reason for this difference.

Query 1:

```
SELECT member_id, record_ts, record_type
FROM record
WHERE member_id = "M-01"
ORDER BY record_ts
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT member_id, record_ts, record_type
FROM record
WHERE member_id = "M-01"
AND time_partition >= "2023-01"
ORDER BY record_ts
```

In both queries, I'm selecting records from the table "record" where "member_id" is equal to "M-01", and I'm ordering the results by the "record_ts" column. However, Query 2 includes an additional condition that filters the records based on the "time_partition" column.

My Question: Why does the first query produce an empty result, while the second query returns results? What could be the reason for this difference in results between these two Hive queries?

I'd appreciate any insights or explanations that can help me understand this behavior better. Thank you!

I tried adding `hive.fetch.task.conversion=none` but that didn't help

Comment: can you pls post - 1. is it external table? is it a table that gets loaded  frequently ? 2. is it old issue or new? 3. is it happening for any columns or only for member id? 4. hive version? Table DDL, sample data

Comment: Hi! here's some more information about my question: 
1. It's not an external table
2. It's a table that gets selected frequently
3. It's a new issue, It's happening for any column as long as the query doesn't have time_partition filter
4. hive-3.1.0

Comment: thank you. anything changed recently  like new col added etc.?

Comment: No, nothing has changed recently as far as I know. Do you have any theories why this is happening? We're really stuck. Why is it when there's a partition filter the query suddenly works, that means the data is there... but when there's no partition filter it returns nothing.

Comment: one possibility is - if you add a new column, the meta data structure changes but data stays constant which makes filter etc. misbehaving.  check if similar thing is happening to other columns or not? does simple `SELECT member_id, record_ts, record_type
FROM record limit 1000` work?

Comment: `SELECT member_id, record_ts, record_type FROM record limit 1000` works. I tried filtering with a different column, 
`SELECT member_id, record_ts, record_type
FROM record
where record_type = "click"
ORDER BY record_ts` for some reason this works!!!
But when I try 
`SELECT member_id, record_ts, record_type
FROM record
where record_type = "click" and member_id = "M-01"
ORDER BY record_ts` it doesn't work

Comment: strange. another ide. can you pls copy the table into another table using `create table bkp as select * from record;` and then try your SQL on this new table. This will avoid any issues with column addition etc. and if this also give you same result, i would question your data and table a close look at your second SQL in your question - why adding partition col filter is returning data.

Comment: `Create table tmptable like record` then
`Insert into tmptable select * from record`
It behaves the same way as the original table. There's only a result when there's a partition filter or when filtering with a different column.

Comment: can you see the difference of explain plan of both SQLs? First SQL should show its scanning whole table or all partitions, second one will scan only one partition. If you can post both plans, we can see something

Comment: First one: 
`explain SELECT member_id, record_ts, record_type
FROM record_bkp
where member_id = "M-01"
AND time_partition >= "2023-01"
ORDER BY record_ts`

Comment: `Plan optimized by CBO.
Vertex dependency in root stage
Reducer 2 <- Map 1 (SIMPLE_EDGE)
Stage-0
Fetch Operator
limit:-1
Stage-1
Reducer 2 llap
File Output Operator [FS_6]
Select Operator [SEL_4] (rows=5 width=319)
Output:["_col0","_col1","_col2"]
<-Map 1 [SIMPLE_EDGE] llap
SHUFFLE [RS_3]
Select Operator [SEL_2] (rows=5 width=224)
Output:["_col0","_col1"]
Filter Operator [FIL_7] (rows=5 width=408)
predicate:(member_id = 'M-01')
TableScan [TS_0] (rows=196211295 width=733)
env_staging@record_bkp,record_bkp, ACID table,Tbl:COMPLETE,Col:PARTIAL,Output:["member_id","record_ts"]`

Comment: second:
`explain SELECT member_id, record_ts, record_type
FROM record_bkp
where member_id = "M-01"
ORDER BY record_ts`

Comment: `Plan optimized by CBO.
Vertex dependency in root stage
Reducer 2 <- Map 1 (SIMPLE_EDGE)
Stage-0
Fetch Operator
limit:-1
Stage-1
Reducer 2 llap
File Output Operator [FS_6]
Select Operator [SEL_4] (rows=5 width=319)
Output:["_col0","_col1","_col2"]
<-Map 1 [SIMPLE_EDGE] llap
SHUFFLE [RS_3]
Select Operator [SEL_2] (rows=5 width=224)
Output:["_col0","_col1"]
Filter Operator [FIL_7] (rows=5 width=408)
predicate:(member_id = 'M-01')
TableScan [TS_0] (rows=459516666 width=766)
env_staging@record_bkp,record_bkp, ACID table,Tbl:COMPLETE,Col:PARTIAL,Output:["member_id","record_ts"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table (`record_staging`) used to populate the `record` table uses `bucketing_version'='2'`, this alters the way data is distributed and organized in the `record_staging` table. So from then on, the `record` table was being populated using a different bucketing strategy. The `record` table’s bucketing strategy is based on the member_id column that’s why it impacts queries related to member_id.

This shift caused records to be stored differently than before, leading to the data issue we’ve observed. To fix this we just need to update the `record` table to use the same bucketing strategy.

```
ALTER TABLE record SET TBLPROPERTIES('bucketing_version'='2');
```